# Autowired parameter as bean declaration parameter

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I have

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/employee/**")
                               .uri("http://localhost:8081/")
                               .id("employeeModule"))
                  .build()
```

But instead of `http:://localhost:8081/` I want to have a dynamically derived value, like:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder,
                                  @Autowired val discoveryService: DiscoveryService) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/employee/**")
                               .uri(discoveryService.getHost())
                               .id("employeeModule"))
```

Is this possible? How should I change the syntax to autowire the DiscoveryService?

Comment: Shouldn't that be automatic (at least it used to be). You should place a route to a service (the name) and it will (at runtime) use that name to resolve to a host/url to forward to.

Comment: I want this uri to be dynamic

Comment: I know what you want, but if you specify the service name the URL will be looked up when needed, hence dynamic.

Comment: You mean place the name of the service instead of the localhost? Can you please post an example with code?

Answer (score 0):

Try out like this:

```
    RouteLocatorBuilder.Builder routes = builder.routes();
    discoveryClient.getServices().forEach(service->routes.route(r -> r.path("/"+service+"/**")
            .uri("lb://"+service).id(service)));
    return routes.build();
```

Comment: The incoming request has a body of request-params. How would I account for them? Not only I need to capture and forward them, but my discoveryService takes as parameter one of the request-param attributes so Id need to be able to do service(requestParamId)

Comment: What do you want to do with your discoveryService?To change the forwarding uri?Or add a parameter to the request?Or just do something in the request chain?

Comment: To change the forwarding uri

Comment: That would require using a custom spring cloud loadbalancer implementation using hints

Comment: @C96 Why do you what to change the forwarding uri? To choose different versions/instantces of a same service?If so,just do as what spencergibb said.

Comment: @spencergibb can that be integrated in the spring cloud gateway or it is something separate?

Answer (score 0):

You can either do:

```kotlin
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder,
                                  // note the absence of val
                                  @Autowired discoveryService: DiscoveryService) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/employee/**")
                               .uri(discoveryService.getHost())
                               .id("employeeModule"))
```

this will autowire the `DiscoveryService` (it also has to be declared as a `@Bean`) **or** you can call the method that declares the `DiscoveryService` directly since Spring will enhance that method with CGLIB so it will only ever create the `DiscoveryService` once:

```kotlin
@Bean
public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
                  .route(r -> r.path("/employee/**")
                               // note the discoveryService() function call
                               .uri(discoveryService().getHost())
                               .id("employeeModule"))

// ...
```